# Tracing object with rotation constraint

Tags: constraints, tracking

I tried making a gun turret that would be pointed at the empty , and that part works so far but the limit rotation does not work at all and the barrel goes up too high:
[image]
The constraints are shown there, I tried changing the order and using locked track and track to but the results are the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the *Limit Rotation* after the *Damped Track* and it will work fine:

Comment: Well you are right, but I thought I tried that, and I discovered that changing the order of modifiers does not update them, and I need to turn one off and on for it to start working

Comment: oh ok interesting information